# Certificate Path validation in Java including CRL validation

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, pki

I have an intermediate certificate chain, a root certificate and a client certificate. I have to verify that they form a valid certificate chain together. This is working great when I have one intermediate certificate with a valid `CRLDistributionPoint` entry. The Java `CertPathValidator` API handles the validation beautifully.

My question was about the scenario when there will be multiple intermediate certificates and each of them might have a `CRLDistributionPoint` entry. Do I need to write additional code to handle this case? Or will Java simply validate against all CRLs? Or is it that the root certificate can delegate CRL Signing to just one certificate?

I tried searching online and could not find any clues. In addition to the answer to my question, it'd be great if someone could point me to a resource about PKI and certificates in general. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt "Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have to add code, the JDK implementation can smoothly handle the validation of a certificate path containing more than one intermediate CA certificates.

Note that the validation code is also tested against the [PKI Test Suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/crypto_apps_infra/pki/pkitesting.html) from the NIST. That test suite tries to provide a comprehensive list of certificate and certificate path validation test cases.

If you want to look at the implementation code, you can look at the OpenJDK implementation : http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/provider/certpath/package-index.html